# Не отображается фрейм

Tags: php, html, css

Создал фрейм с кодом:

```
`<frameset rows="73,*" cols="*" bordercolor="#000000">
    <frame name="login" src="login.php" />
    <frame src="index.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
</frameset>`
```

Сам фрейм код находится в файле register.php. А файл login.php скинул в ту же папку что и верхние файлы. Но отображается только register.php при посещении страницы register.php. Как мне сделать, чтобы при посещении страницы register.php фрейм отображался?

Comment: <body> есть на странице? И к тому же не представляю зачем фрэймы вообще.

Comment: Да, есть. Ну я хочу сделать индекс пхп как у facebook. Внизу регистрация, а сверху вход на сайт. Мог бы просто там поместить формы, без фрейма, но тогда при изменении размера окна, они бы не были видны. Пропадали бы

Answer (score 3):

У тега <frame> есть атрибут name - который задает имя фрейма.

Если в ссылку <а> (или в <form>) добавить атрибут target - в котором указать имя фрейма, то можно, чтоб при нажати на ссылки или кнопку происходил переход не в том окне, где нажали, а в том, которое target.

Что до формы входа, то я бы рекомендовал сделать её position: fixed и раздвижной. То есть в углу экрана болтается уголок с надписью "вход" (естественно он виден при любом разрешении экрана и не прокручивается), а при клике на него выежает форма. И никаких фреймов.

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее о реализации предложенной вами идеи? Мне туда button ставить и сделать фиксед или как? Подробнее можно?

Comment: Делаете DIV со стилем что-то типа:
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 15px;
   left: 100%;
   margin-left: -100px;
   width: 100px;
   z-index: 1000;
}

При клике либо отображаете полную форму посреди экрана, либо делаете данной форме margin-left больше (а саму форму делаете так, чтобы левые 100 рх были только с надписью вход, а правые сколько-то так с самой формой). Ну или так какую-то другую анимацию, на ваш вкус. Конечно проще будет юзать jQuery для этих целей.